# Performing Asynchronous Ajax Requests an Unknown Amount of Times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I need to perform multiple Ajax requests and be able to read the returned data upon a successful call.

I've got an array full of strings, call it `queries` the size of the array is unknown. I need to loop though this array and call this ajax request at each element.

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=" + queries[index] + "&type=track",
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data)
     {
         //do something with data
     }
 });
```

Every solution I've seen to a problem related to mine uses jQuery's `.when()` method. This won't work because I have an unknown amount of times that these requests need to occur and each individual request won't be defined as required by the `.when()` method.

How would I perform all these asynchronous ajax requests?

Comment: What about creating a global array and storing requests in there?

Comment: So you need to perform something after _all_ the queries have returned?

Comment: I don't get what the problem is.. Can't you use `for(i in queries)` loop and make every call? You have to "do sth with data" for each request? You have to do somthing special when ALL requests are done?

Comment: Put all the promises in an array, and use `$.when.apply(null, promiseArray)`.